# Event handling in multiple FXML

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have made this UI (see image) in FXMl. The Top.fxml, Bottom.fxml, Left.fxml, Right.fxml are put under a Main.fxml and arranged via `BorderPane`. The Left.fxml and Right.fxml are in  `SplitPane`.

What I am trying to do is, when the button from Top.fxml clicked it should execute the function in Controller file. Below is the code from the controller file. I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` on `list.setItems(listItems);` .This also happens when I put `list.setItems(listItems);` in the initialize method.

```
@FXML
private Button btn;

@FXML
private ListView<String> list;

ObservableList<String> listItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList("A","B","C","D");

@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

}

public void addToList(ActionEvent event) {

list.setItems(listItems);

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The 'list' variable is null if the code has not been injected correctly, i.e. Top.fxml has not been loaded correctly.
Please provide the code that load the fxml file if you cannot solve the issue.

Comment: I used `<fx:include fx:id="topBar" source="Top.fxml" />` to include the fxml.

Comment: I suggest you check the path of the Top.fxml file. It may be loaded correctly with Scene Builder, but not a runtime (or the opposite)